# ¿Como creo un programa de vehiculos con struct en C?

Tags: c

en mi proyecto debo crear un programa que posea un menu donde me de dos opciones.

En la primera "Listar todas las versiones de un vehiculo " en la cual debo engresarle quien lo fabrico(toyota,suzuki,etc) y el nombre del modelo, dandome como resultado y en la segunda "Validar los vehiculos fabricados" , en esto se escribe el modelo y el programa debe mostrar el vehiculo solicitado (si existe) y en caso de que no este debe responder que no hay tal modelo.

Toda la informacion de los vehiculos esta en un archivo .csv
Por el momento llevo esto, no se utilizar bien los estruct no listas enlazadas por eso aun no se que ponerles, si puderan ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Datos_Vehiculos{
    char Fabricante[],Modelo[],Tipo_Vehiculo[],Tipo_Combustible[],Tipo_Cambio[],Tipo_Traccion[];
    int Year_Fabricacion,Numero_Cilindro;
    float Desplazamiento_Litros;
};

int Buscar{
}

main(){
    FILE *Autos;
    Autos = fopen("vehiculos-diminuto.csv", "r");
    fscanf(Autos,"%d",&nautos);
    int opcion,nautos;
    do{
    printf("Bienvenido, elija una opcion. \n");
    printf(" \n      MENU    \n");
    printf("1. Listar Versiones de Vehiculo\n");
    printf("2. Validar Vehiculo Fabricado\n");
    printf("3. Salir\n");
    printf(" Su opcion fue: ");
    scanf("%d", & opcion);
    fflush(stdin);
    switch (opcion){
        case 1: printf("Ingrese Fabricante y nombre del  modelo:  ");
        scanf("%c %c",)
        break;
        case 2: printf(Ingrese el modelo que desea: );
    }   

    }

}
```

Lo que tengo ahora es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 50
#define LARGO 150

struct Marcas{

char *Marca;
struct Marcas *SgteMa;

};

struct Modelos{

char *Modelo;
struct Modelos *SgteMo;
};

struct Datos{

int Year;
char *Tipo;
float Desplazamiento;
int Cilindros;
char *Combustible;
char *Cambio;
char *Traccion;
struct Datos *SgteDs;

};

struct Marcas *Ingresar_Marca(struct Marcas *Inicio, char Dato[]){

struct Marcas *Nuevo;

Nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct Marcas));
Nuevo -> Marca = Dato;
Nuevo -> SgteMa = Inicio;

return Nuevo;

}

struct Modelos *Ingresar_Modelo(struct Modelos *Inicio, char Dato[]){

struct Modelos *Nuevo;

Nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct Modelos));
Nuevo -> Modelo = Dato;
Nuevo -> SgteMo = Inicio;

return Nuevo;

}

struct Datos *Ingresar_Datos(struct Datos *Comienzo, char Linea[], int Start) 
{

struct Datos *Nuevo;
char Dato[MAX];
int Inicio = Start;
Nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct Datos));
Nuevo -> SgteDs = Comienzo;
return Nuevo;

}

int PuntoComa(int Inicio, char Linea[], char Regreso[]){

int Largo, Num, Total, Cont, Final;
char Dato[MAX];

Largo = strlen(Linea);

for(Num = Inicio; Num < Largo; Num++){

    if(Linea[Num] == ';' || Linea[Num+1] == '\0'){  

        Final = Num;
        Cont = 0;

        for(Total = Inicio; Total < Final; Total++){

            Dato[Cont] = Linea[Total];
            Dato[Cont+1] = '\0';
            Cont++;

        }

        strcpy(Regreso,Dato);   
        return Final+1;

     }
 }
}
main(){

int Inicio, ContPuntoComa;
char Linea[LARGO];
char Dato[MAX];

FILE *Vehiculos;
Vehiculos = fopen("vehiculos-chico.csv","r");

Inicio = 0;

struct Marcas *Marca;
Marca = NULL;
struct Modelos *Modelo;
Modelo = NULL;
struct Datos *AllDatos;
AllDatos = NULL;

while(fgets(Linea,LARGO,Vehiculos) != NULL){

    Inicio = PuntoComa(Inicio,Linea,Dato);
    Marca = Ingresar_Marca(Marca,Dato);

    Inicio = PuntoComa(Inicio,Linea,Dato);
    Modelo = Ingresar_Modelo(Modelo,Dato);

    AllDatos = Ingresar_Datos(AllDatos,Linea,Inicio);

    Inicio = 0;

 }
}
```

Pero con esto tengo un error y es que la marca se cambia por el modelo y el de los datos no guarda nada :(

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu pregunta, ¿puedes concretar un poco?

Comment: no se como usar struct para ordenar los datos que posee el archivo,el profesor dijo que debia usar 3 listas para guardar los datos: uno que tenga las marcas, otro los modelos y otra donde esten las versiones ...en el archivo todo esta separado por punto y coma, y debo crear un programa donde en la primera opcion el usuario deba engresarme la marca,modelo,año de inicio-año de final y debe dar como resultado las versiones de ese modelo y  en la segunda opcion debe ingresar, marca,modelo y desplazamiento para que le diga si existe o no... no se si se entiende un poco mas

Comment: Siento tener que insistir, pero no me acaba de quedar clara cuál es tu duda. ¿no sabes leer de un archivo separado por `;`? ¿no sabes cómo buscar datos dentro de una lista? ¿no sabes recoger los datos del usuario?. Creo que podría ser de ayuda que compartieras lo que has intentado hasta ahora, no sólo el esqueleto de tu programa.

Comment: Pude adelantar eso ahora lo que debo hacer (segun yo, puede que me este enredando) es enlazarlas, guardarlas y ponerlas en el esqueleto del programa para que cuando el usuario me pongo la marca,el modelo y años le de el resultado que quiere... se entiende un poco mas ahora?